# Update a value of a JavaScript variable from another page

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Is it possible to update the value of a variable from another page using JavaScript?

*or*

Is it possible to do this using form on submit, just update the other page, but remain on the page on which the form is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) which performs a get or post action and waiting for the result of the server. This makes it possible to submit a form without jumping to the page.

Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
Or if you use JQuery [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I think to much, I forgot that there is an AJAX. thanks @NovaAetas

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send all the data to be updated via Ajax and simply get the response on the current page You are in.